# In a multi-head MATE desktop environment, how can fullscreen windows be made to respect the dock placement?

Tags: window, mate, fullscreen, dock, mint

I have three displays running with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (X11) and the MATE Mutiny desktop environment. When I bring a window to fullscreen, the resize of the window does not respect the dock and ends up placing the edge of the window beneath the dock. How can this behaviour be changed?

The screenshot below illustrates the window lying behind the dock in the rightmost display of the three displays.

[image]

As has been suggested, I've tried setting each individual display as the primary display but this doesn't prevent the windows from changing to fullscreen *behind* the dock.

Comment: If you can change monitor order, than reconfigure so dock does not appear in screen middle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried changing the monitor orders but I still observe the fullscreening of windows doing under the dock.

Comment: I think it should work if your monitor with dock is moved to left side. If that does not work then it is bug somewhere.